# Calling close() twice on CSVPrinter object

Tags: java

Is calling close() on a already closed CSVPrinter instance a no-op? What about flush()? Didn't find any documentation on this.

Comment: why don't you try it?

Comment: I guess it would take less time to try it rather then ask here.

Comment: @ScaryWombat trying does not prove anything. It may work sometimes and fail occasionally. Stephen C answer is correct - just look at the docs of implemented interfaces.

Comment: Sometimes I wish there was an option to downvote comments :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is calling close() on a already closed CSVPrinter instance a no-op?

The standard contract for a `Closable` is that calling `close()` is idempotent.  The `CSVPrinter` class implements `Closeable`.

> Didn't find any documentation on this.

It is in the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) for `Closeable`.

> What about flush()?

It is unclear what you are asking here.

- Calling `flush()` twice is probably a no-op.
- Calling `flush()` on a closed object is redundant, as is calling `flush()` before you call `close()`.  (A `close()` will try to flush if necessary.)

The generic specification for the behavior for `flush()` does not say what should happen when you flush a closed stream.  In the case of `CSVPrinter`, `flush()` delegates to the `Appendable` that the printer is wrapping.  Hence the behavior of `CSVPrinter.flush()` on a closed printer cannot be specified.

But given the uncertainty, the simple solution is to not call `flush()` before `close()`.  Only flush if you don't intend to close AND if there is a pressing need to push the data ... NOW.

(Unnecessary flushing negates the performance benefits of buffering, both in Java space and in the kernel's I/O stacks.)

Comment: `flush` on a closed object may fail (not sure about particular implementation of `CSVPrinter`, but other implementations of `Flushable` could fail).

Comment: I was getting to that :-)